# Data being duplicated in a database on save

Tags: c#

I am trying to save some data in a database using an INSERT query but it is saving double value on single click. For example I save 'Lahore', it'll save it two times:

Lahore 
Lahore

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = HAMAAD-PC\\SQLEXPRESS ; Initial Catalog = BloodBank; Integrated Security = SSPI ");
try
{
   conn.Open();
   SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("insert into City values('" + txtCity.Text + "')", conn);
   query.ExecuteNonQuery();
   SqlDataReader dt = query.ExecuteReader();

   if (dt.Read())
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Saved....!");
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Not saved.....");
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Failed....." + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Did you ever heard about [Sql Injection](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)??

Comment: You should read the documentation about the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is doing exactly what you told it to.
If you call an `Execute*()` method twice, it will run your query twice.

Answer (score 2):

It's saving twice because you are executing the query twice:

```
query.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataReader dt = query.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving twice.

The executeNonQuery will return the number of rows affected so use this instead.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = HAMAAD-PC\\SQLEXPRESS ; Initial Catalog = BloodBank; Integrated Security = SSPI ");
try
{
   conn.Open();
   SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("insert into City values('" + txtCity.Text + "')", conn);
   var rowsAffected = query.ExecuteNonQuery();

   if (rowsAffected == 1)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Saved....!");
   }
   else
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Not saved.....");
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Failed....." + ex.Message);
}
```